# how to edit "Xorg.conf" to work with ATI HD 5770?

Tags: 10.10, xorg, ati, proprietary

im having issues with my HD 5770 running on the proprietary driver that i get from `"system/administration/additional drivers"`

im using Ubuntu 10.10 and a DVI to VGA converter on a CRT screen .

1. so can i use only Xorg to run my GPU
   with out installing any drivers ?
2. if yes how to make a fully working Xorg
   file ?

Answer (score 1):

I m using same card too.
There is no problem with 11.04 and 11.10.

Only these commands and reboot:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
sudo reboot
```

After restarting, please type to terminal:

```
env LC_ALL=C amdxdg-su -c amdcccle
```

It will open Catalyst Control Center window:

[image: http://ompldr.org/vOXJ2NA]

Answer (score 0):

If you uninstall previous driver then Ubuntu will use the open source driver for your card(radeon driver).

If you use `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reboot it probably will work. Change preferred resolution in System -> Preferences -> Monitor.

Comment: how do i put in the screen res and refresh rates

Comment: You should be able to change that in Monitor settings. If not you will have to change that manually in /etc/X11/xorg.conf. If you change it manually you will have to restart X with following combination: CTRL + ALT + Print Scrn + K.

Comment: can u tell me how to change it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Radeon HD5850, so it isn't exactly the same card, but your experiences should be similar.

In older versions of Ubuntu, the open drivers were not very good and you almost had to use the proprietary drivers. In 11.04, there were great improvements to the open drivers, but there were still a few issues with Unity, although they were minor. In 11.10, there is no doubt that I prefer the open drivers. They're faster, more stable and makes things easier in general.

In other words, unless you have very good reasons not to, I would strongly encourage you to check out the newest versions of Ubuntu and see if the problems just go away.

Answer (score 0):

to ask your question a single command is enough

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

with this your xorg.conf is properly written, it's ok and fully working.

But, if i can suggest you something better than the driver you are actually using, install the proprietary driver from the official website ( first remove the one you have installed from the official repository and every fglrx-related packages ) maybe you can follow the instructions at this page http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page .

There is nothing wrong with the fglrx package from the official repository but it's really outdated and sometimes the latest driver from the official website works better.

I have an XFX XXX 5770 1Gb and everything works like a charm with the latest driver.